# How to get the icon of clicked Marker in google maps android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have groups of marker of different icons in my map and all are clickable.
I want to know the icon of the clicked marker.

I check the docs and couldn't find any method like getMarkerIcon(). Is there any other way?

Thanks

Comment: why would you need such information?

Comment: I want to change the icon based on the previous one. Since I have many , storing it wont help.

Comment: storing them  is the only option .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today , there is no function which returns the icon of clicked marker.
I hope it will come in the next releas.